# PHP Converting UnUnicode characters to Unicode (Full)

Tags: php, unicode, special-characters

I've been trying to convert some special and ununicode characters to the original ones but i didn't get what i needed .
Lets have an example. I have a file in Persian name and i want to upload it. when i upload it the name changes to some strange characters like Ø ! I dont know why (And i dont want to know) but when i start to download it with IDM , the strange name changes back to its original .
Original File Name:      ترمینال_گنبدکاووس.rar
Strange File Name:       ØªØ±Ù…ÛŒÙ†Ø§Ù„_Ú¯Ù†Ø¨Ø¯Ú©Ø§ÙˆÙˆØ³.rar
And this is not just my problem. the file name in every language converts to its own strange characters. and in another example when i want to convert babylon dictionaries (bgl) to stardict (mdx) format, the phonetics are converted to strange characters again.
I want to know that is there an absolute way to convert all these characters back to its original using PHP ???????

Comment: You are messing up your character sets. Multibyte character sets like UTF-16 often look like this when the displaying software expects a single-byte character set.

Comment: I once created a function to failsafe convert UTF8 _and_ UTF32 into proper UTF8: http://php.net/manual/function.utf8-encode.php#102382 I'm not sure if this will help you...

Comment: What filesystem type do you use on the target server? What gives you the 'strange' filenames? Is it an `ls` in terminal or PHP Output?